# How to refresh Gridview in onItemClickListener android studio

Tags: gridview, android-gridview

I use a grid view to display some videos from a specific path in my storage
When i click an item i delete it from its ListMap

In gridview adapter i know how to refresh gridview
i.e

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But in th gridview onItemClickListener method
I don't know how can i refresh it

I tried

```
((BaseAdapter)gridview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But it didn't work

I also tried ChatGPT and searched for it on google and youtube
But all i foud was just waste of time

I have read some articles about gridview
But none of them worked

If anyone know how it can be done
Please let me know in the answer section.